# Magento 2 : Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener containes 1 abstract method

Tags: magento2, composer

I am facing issue when I execute command of upgrade & deploy. I executed **composer update** command.

I know it's repeat question and tried solution But I didn't solve issue yet.

Can anyone please help me to solve it?

**Error :**

> Class Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface::__invoke) in /var/wwww/html/m242/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Mvc/Bootstrap/InitParamListener.php on line 32

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, copy the setup folder from magento 2.3.7 another project or download it from magento git repo: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3.7/setup

It works for all others magento versions, just change 2.3.7 to your magento upgrade version. For example, you want to upgrade to magento 2.4.3, the setup folder can get in https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4.3/setup